# remove div completely and add again

Tags: javascript, css

i need to remove a div(#pop1) by clicking same div and add again that div by click other div (#pop2) and need to remove that div(#pop2).

Check my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ramswarnak/kjTBG/2/)

i wrote the code to remove  div but how to add it again.

```
$(".del").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().remove();     
})
```

Comment: Use `.detach()` instead of `.remove()`, storing the reference in a variable. Use **unique** `id` attributes. Don't use inline event handlers. And actually include the jQuery library in your jsFiddle

Comment: how about using `.hide()` and `.show()` rather actually removing it?

Comment: can you help with demo.

Comment: what actually do u need??
do u need to hide the clicked div and show others??

Comment: i need  to remove first div, by click on it and when i click the second div, need to remove  second div and add first div again..

Comment: Simply use .hide() and .show() for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [[DEMO]](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/kjTBG/10/). I have bind it on `.player` class as the `del` class is too small. You can change that accordingly!

```
$(".player").bind('click', function(){
    $('.player').show();
   $(this).hide();     
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Like one of the comment's suggestion, use `.hide()` and `.show()` if you wish to hide and show the `div`

But, if you want to `remove` the `div` then attach it  later, use a global variable to save the `div`

`var $div=$(".del"); \\ the global variable`

then before removing it using your `.remove()` code add `$div=$(".del")`.

and afterwards you can use it to attach the `div` to a parent element by `$("#parentDiv").append($div)`

PS: can't access your fiddle in my network now, so can't post an updated fiddle

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are after:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var cached = null;

$(".del").click(function(){
    if(cached != null){
     $('body').prepend(cached);   
    }
   cached = $(this).parent().detach();
})
});
</script>
```

**Note:** Remove your click handlers that you've written inline:

```
<a class="del" href='#' onclick="remove('rem')" ><div id="pop3"></div></a>
```